# ArrayAdapter getView() not being called

Tags: listview, gridview, android-arrayadapter

I'm trying to populate a GridView from my android activity's layout using a custom ArrayAdapter in which I overrided getView(). When I run the app, the GridView shows up on the screen but completely empty. I've deduced that the issue is that getView() never gets called. I did check to see that the ArrayList was not empty. I used some log statements (similar to System.out.print() for those that aren't familiar with Android programming), and found that my ArrayList being passed to the adapter was not empty, however the getCount() method of my adapter always returned 0.  I've tried to look through some android source code to find when getView() is supposed to get called, which led to obtainView() and mObjects. It all seems pretty straight forward and I haven't found anything wrong.  Barring some sort of anti-miracle explanation, so far I've come up empty (likely due to me being an amateur programmer). Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Activity file:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.*;
import android.widget.*;

public class LevelMapActivity extends FragmentActivity implements View.OnClickListener{

    public final int TOTAL_LEVELS = 12;//TODO Set TOTAL_LEVELS to figure out how many levels exist.
    public final int COLUMNS = 5;

    GridView grid;
LevelSelectorAdapter adapter;
ArrayList<LevelSelector> levels;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_level_map);

    grid = (GridView)findViewById(R.id.GridView_LevelMap);
    grid.setNumColumns(COLUMNS);

    levels = new ArrayList<LevelSelector>();

    for(int i=0; i<TOTAL_LEVELS/5; i++){
        for(int j=0; j<5; j++){
            LevelSelector levelSelector = new LevelSelector(this, i*COLUMNS+j+1);
            levels.add((i*COLUMNS)+j, levelSelector);
        }
    }
    for(int j=0; j<TOTAL_LEVELS%5; j++){
        LevelSelector levelSelector = new LevelSelector(this, TOTAL_LEVELS-(COLUMNS-1)+j);
        levels.add(j+TOTAL_LEVELS-COLUMNS, levelSelector);
    }

    adapter = new LevelSelectorAdapter(this, R.layout.level_selector, levels);
    grid.setAdapter(adapter);

}//ends onCreate()

@Override
public void onPause(){

    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onPause();

}//ends onPause()

@Override
public void onClick(View view){

    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}//ends onClick()

}//ends Class
```

Adapter file:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

import android.content.Context;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.*;
import android.widget.*;

public class LevelSelectorAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<LevelSelector>{

Context context;
int resource;
ArrayList<LevelSelector> levelSelectors;

public LevelSelectorAdapter(Context context, int resource, ArrayList<LevelSelector> levelSelectors){

    super(context, resource);
    this.context = context;
    this.resource = resource;
    this.levelSelectors = levelSelectors;

}//ends LevelSelectorAdapter()

public static class ViewHolder{
    public TextView level;
    public TextView time;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent){

    View view = convertView;
    ViewHolder holder;

    if(view == null){
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        view = inflater.inflate(resource, null);
        holder = new ViewHolder();
        holder.level = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.TextView_LevelSelector_Level);
        holder.time = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.TextView_LevelSelector_Time);
        view.setTag(holder);
    }
    else{
        holder = (ViewHolder)view.getTag();
    }

    final LevelSelector levelSelector = levelSelectors.get(position);
    if(levelSelector != null){
        holder.level.setText(Integer.toString(levelSelector.getLevel()));
        holder.time.setText(Integer.toString(levelSelector.getTime()));
    }

    return view;

}//ends getView()

}//ends Class
```

Answer (score 2):

Because of one of the way I had experimented with the adapter to try to override the `getView()` method, I had previously no need for the array passed to the adapter in its constructor.
Passing the array to the super constructor causes it to be initiated and therefore usable within the `getCount()` method. That's why `getCount()` came out to 0 each time, even though the array was not empty.